# How to remove elements by css selector ( tags, classes and ids ) with Domcrawler?

Tags: dom, symfony, domdocument

How could I implement [this solution here](http://bit.ly/1bw75LK) with [Domcrawler](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler)?

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$crawler = new Crawler();
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/somepage.html');
$crawler->addHtmlContent($content, 'UTF-8');
$content = $crawler->filter('#main-content');

// Remove content by tag and by css selector.

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    $crawler = new Crawler($html,$url);

    $document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $root = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('_root'));
    $crawler->rewind();
    $root->appendChild($document->importNode($crawler->current(), true));
    $domxpath = new \DOMXPath($document);

    foreach ($selectorsToRemove as $selector) {
        $crawlerInverse = $domxpath->query(CssSelector::toXPath($selector));
        foreach ($crawlerInverse as $elementToRemove) {
            $parent = $elementToRemove->parentNode;
            $parent->removeChild($elementToRemove);
        }
    }
    $crawler->clear();
    $crawler->add($document);
```

Comment: I've entered your code as a feature request ( http://bit.ly/1adIkGk ) into the DomCrawler component repository. If the request gets accepted then a new method called "remove" will be available. Hence the solution implementation will become pretty much only one line of code '$crawler->remove(array('script'));'

Answer (score 1):

The `Crawler` class extends [`\SplObjectStorage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) and when the Crawler receives the HTML, it uses the `attach()` method to add each element to the storage.

This means that a `detach()` method is also available on the crawler object. I haven't tested the following, but I would assume this might do the job.

```
$crawlerInverse = $crawler->filter('script');

foreach ($crawlerInverse as $elementToRemove) {
    if ($crawler->contains($elementToRemove)) {
       $crawler->detach($elementToRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes a lot of sense but the detach method is not removing the element from the main object.

Comment: Interesting. I think this is because the crawler initialises with only the elements matching as the objects and any child nodes are not stored. BTW, you suggested edit is correct, there's no need to clone the crawler so I've applied your changes.

Comment: The filter method does not change the object but returns the filtered result, so the way it was b4 wasn't doing anything on $crawlerInverse. I think I've found the way to do what I want, I will post it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html):

> The DomCrawler component eases DOM navigation for HTML and XML documents.

and also:

> While possible, the DomCrawler component is not designed for manipulation of the DOM or re-dumping HTML/XML.

DomCrawler is designed to extract details from DOM documents rather than modifying them.

**However...**

Since PHP passes objects by reference, and *Crawler* is basically a wrapper for [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)s, it's technically possible to modify the underlying DOM document:

```php
// will remove all divs with a class .toRemove
$crawler->filter('div.toRemove')->each(function ($node) {
    foreach ($crawler as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/jakzal/8dd52d3df9a49c1e5922

Answer (score 1):

Use a common function like:

```
function removeCrawlerNode($crawler_node) {

    foreach($crawler_node as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

Then find the section of crawler code you want to search in (say class .sample_section) and if it exists then make a remove_tag_array with all tags you want to remove:

```
if($crawler->filter('.sample_section')->count() > 0) {

    $remove_tag_array = array("br", "b", "img", "div", "u", "i");

    $sub_crawler = $crawler->filter('.sample_section');

    foreach ($remove_tag_array as $tag) {
        $sub_crawler->filter($tag)->each(function ($node) {
            removeCrawlerNode($node);
        });
    }
}
```